# ASP.NET Core Odata Service Post not working

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I implemented a ODATA Service in my ASP.NET Core application. The GET function is working fine, but I have some problems with the POST function.

If I excecute a POST the programm is excecuting the right method but I don't receive any data.
Is there anything missing in my code?

Controller:

```
    [EnableCors]
    [ODataRoutePrefix("documents")]
    public class DocumentController : ODataController
    {
        [ODataRoute]
        [EnableQuery]
        public Document PushDocument([FromBody]Document doc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DomentID: " + doc.Id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dokument: " + doc.RawDocument);

            return doc;
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you hit the method but the `doc` is null?How do you send the post the data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `[FromBody]`, you need to send data as `Content-Type: application/json`,in postman：
[image]

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddOData();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc(b =>
        {
            b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel()); 
        });
    }
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Document>("Documents");
        builder.EntitySet<Press>("Presses");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Comment: That's exactely how I did it but unfortunately still no content. This is what I receive from the server after executing the post.
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:65475/odata/$metadata#documents/$entity",
    "Id": 0,
    "RawDocument": null
}

Comment: @zippy234  could not reproduce that, I post my startup above

Comment: I'm not able to use version 2.2. Maybe this is the problem?
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

Comment: @zippy234 I do not think that will have effect.Maybe you could share a reproducible demo...